# What are some good tools/practises for aspect level sentiment analysis?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, opennlp, gate

I am planning to get some review data from tripadvisor and I want to be able to extract hotel related aspects and assign polarity to them and classify them as negative or positive.

What tools can I use for this purpose and how and where do I start? I know there are some tools like GATE, Stanford NLP, Open NLP etc, but would I be able to perform the above specific tasks? If so, please let me know an approach to go forward. I am planning to use Java as the choice of programming language and would like to use some APIs

Also, should I go ahead with a rule based approach or a ML approach that uses a trained corpus of reviews, so some other approach completely?

P.S : I am new to NLP and I need some help to go forward.

Answer (score 0):

Stanford `CoreNLP` has lot of features in one package

- POS Tagger
- NER Model
- Sentiment Analysis
- Parser

But in Apache OpenNLP package consist

- Sentence Detector
- POS tagger
- NER
- Chunker

But they don't have built in feature to find out Sentiment polarity So you have to  pass your tags to other libraries such like [SentiwordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/) to find out the polarity.

I used used `OpenNLP` and Stanford `Core NLP`. But for both you need to modify sentiment corpus with respect to restaurant domain.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have a corpus? Are there any other appraoches available? pardon my ignorance. I am new to all these concepts

Comment: You likely need to produce your own corpus, unless you can find something very similar to your particular text domain (hotel reviews). You could do this automatically by storing review-star rating mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ConceptNet` (http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/). See for instance here (at the bottom of the page): https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/API how to "see 20 things in English with the most positive affect:"